# optimise python code for random generator

Tags: python

Could you please help me to optimize my first python program, I am trying to define a random generator, but somehow when I put a big number it hangs...

```
def rand(seed, x):
    if x == 1:
        return seed
    elif x == 2:
        return 1237
    elif x == 3:
        return 345892
    else:
        return ((31 * rand(seed, (x - 3))) + (103 * rand(seed, (x - 2))) + (7 * rand(seed, (x - 1))) + 500003) % 1000001
```

please try with:

```
print(rand(5, 5)), the result is : 506860
```

but when you use a bigger number its a problem, example:

```
print(rand(50, 50))
```

Comment: I'd look into dynamic programming. In this case, it would be `O(n)` instead of `O(1.83..^n)`.

Comment: `@functools.lru_cache` could help a little

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):

```
def rand(seed, x):
  table = [seed, 1237, 345892]
  for _ in range(x - 3):
    next_num = table[-3] * 31 + table[-2] * 103 + table[-1] * 7 
    next_num += 500003
    next_num %= 1000001
    table.append(next_num)
  return table[-1]
```

The reason this is faster is that it only calculates each value once, while your code calculates things exponentially.

This algorithm is `O(n)` (for loop of length `x - 3`), while your algorithm was `O(1.83...^n)` (`1.83^3=1+1.83+1.83^2`).

Alternately, as suggested in the comments, you can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache()
def rand(seed, x):
  # insert your code here
```

This works in almost the same way as the previous code, but uses a decorator to memoize results instead of storing them in a list.